# Select entries from matrices according to indices in another matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have matrices:

```
a=  0.8147    0.1270    0.6324
    0.9058    0.9134    0.0975

b=  0.2785    0.9649    0.9572
    0.5469    0.1576    0.4854
    0.9575    0.9706    0.8003

c = 0.1419    0.7922
    0.4218    0.9595
    0.9157    0.6557
```

and also I have another matrix

```
   I=  1 3 1 1
       2 1 3 2
```

I want to get `d` matrix such that

```
d= a(1,3) b(3,1) c(1,1)
   a(2,1) b(1,3) c(3,2)
```

where indices come as two consecutive entries of `I` matrix.
This is one example I get. However, I get different size matrices for `a,b,c,..` and `I`.

**Added**: `I` is `m x (n+3)` which includes indices, and other `(n+2)` matrices which have corresponding entries are `X,A1,A2,...,An,Y`. When `n` is given, `A1,A2,...,An` matrices are generated.

Can someone please help me to write Matlab code for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`varargin`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html). Assuming that your matrices are constructed such that you can form your desired output in the way you want *(Updated according to [Carmine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971435/6469393)):*

```
function out = IDcombiner(I, varargin)
out = zeros(size(I, 1), nargin-1);
idx = @(m, I, ii) (sub2ind(size(m), I(:, ii), I(:, ii+1)));
for ii = 1:1:nargin-1
    out(:, ii) = varargin{ii}(idx(varargin{ii}, I, ii));
end
```

Now using this function you can make your selection on a flexible number of inputs:

```
out = IDcombiner(I, a, b, c)

out =

    0.6324    0.9575    0.1419
    0.9058    0.9572    0.6557
```

There is also a one-liner solution, which **I do not recommend,** since it dramatically decreases the readability of the code and doesn't help you gain much:

```
IDcombiner = @(I,varargin) ...
    cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) varargin{x}(sub2ind(size(varargin{x}), ...
    I(:,x), I(:,x+1))), 1:nargin-1, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Comment: How does 'varargin' look like @erfan? E.g., could you please write corresponding 'varargin' for the given example? Thanks

Comment: Take a look, I have linked the matlab documentation on it. It lets you pass a flexible number of inputs to your function.

Comment: I included an example according to your matrices @user6951884

Comment: Thanks @ erfan. How does `varargin` work if I generate these `a,b,c,...` in an array such as `{rand(s,r), rand(r,r,n), rand(r,s)}`? Here `rand(r,r,n)` means `n` number of `r *r` matrices (I am not sure this is the right way to code). Because I randomly generate those matrices with variable parameter ``n.

Comment: If you combine the matrices before passing them to the function, you do not need `varargin` anymore. [`rand`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) doesn't work in that way also. You will need to make another function to build multiple random matrices if you want to do it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a matrix is not interpreted as a list of indices, but you can have this if you use sub2ind. To use it you need the size of the matrix you are addressing. Let's make an example starting with a:

```
a(sub2ind(size(a), I(:,1), I(:,2)))
```

The code does not change if you first assign the newly generated matrices to a variable name.

will use the column `I(:,1)` as rows and `I(:,2)` as columns.

To make the code more readable you can define an anonymous function that does this, let's call it idx:

```
idx = @(m,I,i)(sub2ind(size(m), I(:,i), I(:,i+1)))
```

So finally the code will be

```
d = [a(idx(a,I,1)), b(idx(b,I,2)), c(idx(c,I,3))]
```

The code does not change if you first assign the newly generated matrices to a variable name.

**Other details**

Let's make an example with 2 central matrices:

```
a = rand(3,1)   % 3 rows, 1 column
b = rand(3,3)   % 3 rows, 3 columns
c = rand(3,3)   % another squared matrix
d = rand(3,1)   % 3 rows, 1 column
```

The definition of the anonymous function is the same, you just change the definition of the output vector:

```
output = [a(idx(a,I,1)), b(idx(b,I,2)), c(idx(c,I,3)), d(idx(d,I,3))]
```

Keep in mind that following that pattern you always need a `I` matrix with `(n_matrices + 1)` columns.

**Generalization**

Let's generalize this code for a number n of central matrices of size rxr and for "side matrices" of size rxc. I will use some values of those parameters for this example, but you can use what you want.

Let me generate an example to use:

```
r = 3;
c = 4;
n = 3;

a = rand(r,c);   % 2D array
b = rand(r,r,n); % 3D array, along z = 1:n you have 2D matrices of size rxr
c = rand(r,c); 

I =  [1 3 1 2 1 3; 2 1 3 1 1 1];
```

The code I wrote can easily be extended using `cat` to append matrices (note the 2 in the function tells MATLAB to append on the direction of the columns) and a for cycle:

```
idx = @(m,I,i)(sub2ind(size(m), I(:,i), I(:,i+1)))

d = a(idx(a,I,1));
for i = 1:n
    temp = b(:,:,i);
    d = cat(2,d,temp(idx(tmp,I,i+1)));
end
d = cat(2,d,c(idx(c,I,n+1)));
```

If you really don't want to address anything "by hand", you can use cell arrays to put all the matrices together and then cyclically apply the anonymous function to each matrix in the cell array.

Comment: Well in this way you don't need to use `varargin` because you manually apply the anonymous function to each of the matrices.

The purpose of this trade-off of manual work is that in this way you can refrain from using cycles (that is better practice in MATLAB), you don't need a separate function file to use this in your code (that happens if you are writing a script and not a function), and it's just two lines.

Comment: Thanks @ Carmine. How does this work if I generate these `a,b,c,...` in an array such as `{rand(s,r), rand(r,r,n), rand(r,s)}`? Here `rand(r,r,n)` means `n` number of `r *r` matrices (i am not sure this is the right way to code). I even do not know how to pass such array to `varargin`

Comment: As I understand, in your code, I need to write `output` manually. But if I know 1st and last matrices, and no. of central matrices  depends on parameter `n`, then it may difficult to write `output` for every `n`.

Comment: I am also concern of it.

Comment: OP I am not sure I understand exactly what from the text you added in the description 

@Frey I added a generalization in the answer